# Return to old position in scrollview when returning from another view controller swift iOS 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8, scrollview

When returning from another view controller into a scrollview where i came from, the scrollview is reset to the top and i have to scroll all the way down to the place i was before. How can i keep the old scrollview position remembered inside the scrollview? The scrollview is pretty large (4000).
        import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var admobBanner: GADBannerView!
@IBOutlet var PausePlay: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

ScrollView.contentSize.height = 4000

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()  
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create a `CGPoint` variable called `currentContentPosition` (or any other thing)

2 - Before loading the next page set the variable that you just created to be equal to the content position (in this case `currentContentPosition = yourScrollView.contentOffset`)

3 - When the page reappears (on viewWillAppear) reset the scrollView to the content position you saved (`yourScrollView.contentOffset = currentContentPosition`)